# Using the terminal to open a folder which contains japanese characters

Tags: command-line, directory, japanese

I need to use the terminal to open a folder with a Japanese title. If I use - ls to see the name of the folder, all it shows is: " ■ ■ ■ ■ " . The actual title is: " 源氏物語 ".

What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the Ubuntu Mono font not supporting Japanese characters. Try installing the Advanced Settings tool, and changing the Monospace font to something that supports Japanese characters.

Comment: Thanks. How can I do this, using just the Terminal?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

You can then open the tool, and go the the Fonts Panel, where you should see an entry for "Monospace Font", which you can select from all the fonts installed on your system.

The program can be run by typing `gnome-tweak-tool` in the terminal.

Comment: You don't need gnome-tweak-tool. You can change the font in the terminal itself by going to `Edit->Profile Preferences`.

Comment: Also, it could be the filename being encoded in a different character set. Changing the font wouldn't necessarily help in that case. The folder could be renamed to the correct set of characters in UTF-8 instead, and it would just work.